# Enable caching on nginx

Tags: nginx, cache, wordpress

I have my own VPS with  CentOS 6 and nginx and I want to enable caching. To test it, if it is enabled successfully I use the Google PageSpeed Insight.
My problem is that I don't have much experience where I have to enable caching and where I can set how long an image for example is cached and so on. 
Thats what I found on the internet and tried so far:

1. creating directories: `/etc/nginx/sites-available` and `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` because they didn't exist somehow.
2. Linking the created directories here: `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` with adding `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` at the end of the file but before the last `}`
3. Creating the file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/my-site.com.conf`:

   ```
   server {
   listen       80;
   server_name  localhost;

   location / {
       root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
       index  index.html index.htm;
   }

   location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
       expires 15d;
   }

   location ~*  \.(pdf)$ {
       expires 30d;
   }
   ```

   }
4. Linking the conf file: `ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/my-site.com.conf  /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/my-site.com.conf`
5. do `service nginx restart`

I use my website for WordPress.

So whenever I test my page with PageSpeed Insight or other pagespeed tools it says that I don't use caching for my header.png, javascripts and so on. But I dont get some errors, even if I check the configuration files with `nginx -t` which shows this:

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Do I have forgotten something?

This is my complete nginx config: http://pastebin.com/wxnzzePT

The `default.conf` from the `conf.d` folder: http://pastebin.com/KUH2tSrD

Comment: Please show your complete nginx configuration, there are quite certainly other parts of the configuration that affect things. And also, you should have used your Linux distribution's native way of adding to nginx configuration. The `sites-enabled` scheme is used in Debian / Ubuntu systems, and is there automatically when you have installed the nginx packets.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I added my nginx config in my original post. How can I add this to the nxing config with CentOS?

Comment: I am not familiar with CentOS way of doing nginx configuration.

Comment: Most likely the configuration is done in the `conf.d` directory. Please also show the contents of `default.conf` in `conf.d`.

Comment: They say [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17415606/2514164) that I can just create those directories 'by hand' but of course I don't know if this is right. I added the default.conf file. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the caching directives to your `default.conf` file, and remove this new file you created.

Your new file is only used when users visit the site using `http://localhost`. In addition, your new file configuration is using different paths compared to your `default.conf` file.

Also, the `root` directive inside a `location` block is bad practice.

So, your `default.conf` should look like this:

```
#
# The default server
#
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    server_name  213.165.xx.xx;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    root   /var/www/wordpress;

    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;

    }

    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
        expires 15d;
    }

    location ~*  \.(pdf)$ {
        expires 30d;
    }

    location /admin {
        auth_basic "Administrator Login";
        auth_basic_user_file /var/www/admin/.htpasswd;
    }

    #!!! IMPORTANT !!! We need to hide the password file from prying eyes
    # This will deny access to any hidden file (beginning with a .period)
    location ~ /\. { deny  all; }

    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }


    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           /var/www/wordpress;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```